# Python: Select linter isn't showing on the command palette on VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, linter

I have tried changing the linter through the command palette but I can't find the python:select linter option. I have switched to docstyle via the command palette before and now I'm trying to switch to Flake8. I am currently using Pylint, Please how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you install the flake8 extension?

Comment: I installed flake8 extension @JonSG

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade **Python** extension version to `v2023.16.0`.

[image]

However, this setting has been gradually deprecated, and lint extensions are now introduced, such as [Pylint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.pylint), [flake8](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.flake8), [mypy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.mypy-type-checker). You can directly install extensions to use instead of installing these modules in the python environment.

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_choose-a-linter